Attempted to navigate before mounting
I'm having this problem with expo routing, I can't go to the sign-in page as it gives me: Error: Attempted to navigate before mounting the Root Layout component. Ensure the Root Layout component is rendering a Slot, or other navigator on the first render., js engine: hermes the initial configuration is as follows. Every time I want to go to sign-in I get the error.
app/_layout.tsx:

// Expo router
import { Stack, Redirect, useRootNavigationState } from 'expo-router';

// Screens
import SignIn from './screens/sign-in';
import InitialScreen from './screens/initial-screen';

const RootLayout = () => {
  const [session, setSession] = useState<Session | null>(null);
  const rootNavigationState = useRootNavigationState();

  useEffect(() => {

    supabase.auth.getSession().then(({ data: { session } }) => {
      setSession(session)
    })

    supabase.auth.onAuthStateChange((_event, session) => {
      setSession(session)
    })
  }, []);

  return(
    session && session.user ? <Stack /> : <InitialScreen />
  )
}

export default RootLayout;

The first page which is the initialScreen is the following and is where you click "Enter", after that I get the aforementioned error
app/screens/initial-screen.tsx:
// React
import React, {useState} from 'react';

// React-native
import { useRouter, Link } from 'expo-router';

// React-native
import { 
  View, 
  Text, 
  StyleSheet, 
  Image, 
  AppState,
  TouchableOpacity
} from 'react-native';

// Supabase
import { supabase } from '../../lib/supabase';

// Safe area insets
import { useSafeAreaInsets } from 'react-native-safe-area-context';

const InitialScreen = () => {
  const insets = useSafeAreaInsets();
  const route = useRouter();

  AppState.addEventListener('change', (state) => {
    if (state === 'active') {
      supabase.auth.startAutoRefresh()
    } else {
      supabase.auth.stopAutoRefresh()
    }
  })
  
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Image source={upperCircle} style={styles.rightImage} />
      
      <View style={[styles.middleContainer, {paddingLeft: insets.left + 10, paddingRight: insets.right + 10}]}>
        <View style={styles.imageAndTextContainer}>
          <Text style={styles.createText}>
            ¡Bienvenido/a! 
          </Text>

          <Text style={styles.smallText}>
            some-text...
          </Text>
        </View>
      </View>
      
      <View style={[styles.buttonContainer, {paddingBottom: insets.bottom + 20}]}>
        <TouchableOpacity style={styles.loginButton} onPress={() => route.push('/sign-in')}>
          <Text style={styles.loginText}>Entrar</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
        {/* <Link href='/' style={styles.loginButton}>
          <Text style={styles.loginText}>Entrar</Text>
        </Link> */}
        <View style={styles.registerButton}>
          <Text style={styles.registerText}>Registrarse</Text>
        </View>
      </View>
      <Image source={footerIcon} style={styles.footerIcon} />
    </View>
  );
}

export default InitialScreen;


